# What is the meaning of Karma runner log times

Tags: debugging, angularjs, karma-runner

I've got a very simple question which I've tried to find out but without satisfactory results.

Example is underneath:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox
INFO [Chrome 28.0 (Linux)]: Connected on socket id MIsxYm-yXOtkIlbXrkr4
INFO [Chrome 28.0 (Linux)]: Connected on socket id Ek6biR3iiKgej2a-rkr5
INFO [Firefox 21.0 (Linux)]: Connected on socket id OcDqEq-VZ5o7tCjNrkr6
Chrome 28.0 (Linux): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (1.655 secs / 1.392 secs)
Chrome 28.0 (Linux): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (2.131 secs / 1.659 secs)
Firefox 21.0 (Linux): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (2.351 secs / 1.414 secs)
TOTAL: 6 SUCCESS
```

The question is what exactly these times (1.655 secs / 1.392 secs) means?

Correct me if I created a bad main question (title) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two numbers are `totalTime`/`netTime` [source](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/2b359b8ef6a8e81ea6daed7d468d2e1b057e8a99/lib/reporters/Base.js). The total time is wall clock time from start to end, and the net time is the sum of all the time spent in individual tests [source](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/42bf787f87304e6be23dd3dac893b3c3f77d6764/lib/browser.js).